# Check if Array has exact Key Value object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a simple check to see if this array has an exact key value pair.

for example

```
testArray = [
   { "key1": "value1" },
   { "key2": "value2" },
   { "key1": "value2" )
]
```

How do I check to see if the array contains the exact object { "key1" : "value2" }?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In modern browsers,

```
testArray.some(function(o){return o["key1"] === "value2";})
```

will be `true` if pair is found, otherwise `false`.

This assumes each object contains only one key/value pair, and that the value is never `undefined`.

Comment: +1, I like your edit. Also kudos for use of .some() :)

Comment: @Alex I would have missed it were it not for your comment. :)

Comment: Yikes . . . there are an awful lot of people out there still using IE8 and earlier . . .

Comment: @talemyn Hence his preface, "In modern browsers," ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a huge fan of the term "modern browsers" . . . everybody seems to have a different idea of what that means.   :D

Comment: Works great! and it exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

```
testArray.find(key => key.key1 === 'value1')
```

Comment: you should use the strict equality operator, ===, unless you really really want JS's type coercion.

Comment: Also, any version of IE this wouldn't work... and you have to use polyfill or create the function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You first want to check to see if the key exists in the object (using `.hasOwnProperty()`) **AND** if that key values references a "value" value that matches the one that you are looking for.  Teh code is pretty straightforward:

```
var testKey = "some_key";
var testVal = "some_val";

for (i=0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    if ((testArray[i].hasOwnProperty(testKey)) && (testArray[i][testKey] === testVal)) {
        // positive test logic
        break;   // so that it doesn't keep looping, after finding a match
    } 
    else {
        // negative test logic
    }
}
```